# How to get path to current user temporary folder on MAC Xcode C++

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

I am developing a Console application (Command line tool) 
on Xcode using C++.

How to get path to current users temporary folder.

Basically I want to create a text file on MAC OS 10.8 in users 
temporary folder.

Comment: as far as i remember path to user folder would be `~/`and from there you can access temporary folder

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just open it in `/tmp`.  On my Mac, at least, it's a link to `/private/tmp`.

Comment: i mean getting path programmatically from Xcode

Answer (score 1):

See 
getenv("TMPDIR")

If it returns the needed path.

This is a list with all the env variables.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man7/environ.7.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/7/environ

You can use **mktemp** to create a file in the temp directory
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/mktemp.3.html

---

Comment: it does give me the temporary folder path, but not for the current user.

Comment: A warning, also - getenv("TMPDIR") will return NULL if you run your tool as sudo.

Answer (score 1):

use confstr() to get the temporary directory (un-accessed files get deleted after 3 days by the system) and the cache directory (files won't get deleted by the system).

```
% cat confstr.c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/syslimits.h>

int main() {
    char buf[PATH_MAX];
    size_t len = PATH_MAX;
    size_t s = confstr(_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR, buf, len);
    printf("_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR(len:%d): %s\n", (int)s, buf);
    s = confstr(_CS_DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR, buf, len);
    printf("_CS_DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR(len:%d): %s\n", (int)s, buf);
    return 0;
}
% cc confstr.c -o confstr -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -arch x86_64 -arch arm64
% ./confstr     
_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR(len:50): /var/folders/hg/rprr5xfn1vsd17dbtzqttg640000gn/T/
_CS_DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR(len:50): /var/folders/hg/rprr5xfn1vsd17dbtzqttg640000gn/C/
% sudo ./confstr         
_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR(len:50): /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/
_CS_DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR(len:50): /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/
```