# Get private/var/folders cache folder path with cocoa on mac os

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, caching, persistence

I'm developing an app and I need to store some files on the macOs cache folder. Since the path changes for every user I cannot determine it. For exemple mine is:

```
/var/folders/_9/q7r9pg8s31g5m96jf7q3h3j80000gn/C/
```

I know that methods like

```
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSAllDomainsMask, YES);
```

But it's only give me:

> "/Users/me/Library/Caches" -- 
>   "/Library/Caches" -- 
>   "/System/Library/Caches"

Which is not I need. I'm looking for an equivalent to `NSTemporaryDirectory()` for cache folder.

The only way I found to get it is to use the terminal and type `getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extend the Caches folder by adding a directory, like this:

```
NSString *path = nil;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
if ([paths count])
{
    NSString *bundleName =
    [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
    path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:bundleName];
}
```

Based on https://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/temporary-files-and-folders-in-cocoa.html

Answer (score 0):

[How to get path to current user temporary folder on MAC Xcode C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879792/how-to-get-path-to-current-user-temporary-folder-on-mac-xcode-c/75392158#75392158)

```
char buf[PATH_MAX];
size_t len = PATH_MAX;
size_t s = confstr(_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR, buf, len);
printf("_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR(len:%d): %s\n", (int)s, buf);
s = confstr(_CS_DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR, buf, len);
printf("_CS_DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR(len:%d): %s\n", (int)s, buf);

% ./confstr     
_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR(len:50): /var/folders/hg/rprr5xfn1vsd17dbtzqttg640000gn/T/
_CS_DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR(len:50): /var/folders/hg/rprr5xfn1vsd17dbtzqttg640000gn/C/
% sudo ./confstr         
_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR(len:50): /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/
_CS_DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR(len:50): /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/
```